# pyqtgraph - ImportError: No module named pyqtgraph

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, pyqtgraph

Recently I downloaded pyqtgraph module. I ran the build and install after extract the folder, however when I ran a simple example like under here

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
y = np.random.normal(size=1000)
pg.plot(x, y, pen=None, symbol='o')  ## setting pen=None disables line drawing
```

I got a error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
import pyqtgraph as pg
ImportError: No module named pyqtgraph
```

I am runnin on ubuntu 14.04 and pyqtgraph is under /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages. Does anybody can help me?

Comment: Downloaded using what? Did you use pip/conda?

Comment: seeing this same issue on osx ventura. The package is installed, but still getting this error.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a package installed for that (or, any module in general), run:

```
sudo pip install (modulename)
```

and

```
sudo pip3 install (modulename)
```

for Python3.

So in this case, try `sudo pip install pyqtgraph`. worked for me.